# Ansible acessing vars prompt value to check with multiple values in a dict

Tags: ansible

I have a vars data type file:

```yaml
foo:
  foo_root_path: faaa
  foo_dest_path: baa
bar:
  bar_root_path: xyz
  bar_dest_path: wxy
baz:
  baz_root_path: abc
  baz_dest_path: def
```

I have a playbook which prompts user to see the type of data I am getting, if it is a `foo`, a `bar` or a `baz`.

I am creating a role to check if `vars prompt == foo` then access values in `foo` and use them to execute a copy command.

I am new to Ansible and trying to understand

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-complex-variable-data and
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html

What I have now is this, where for every when condition I am repeating my commands but I want to use loops and conditionals:

```yaml
role:
when: "'foo' == {{ data_type }}"

- name: move foo data from source to destination

  copy:
    src: '{{ foo_root_path }}/{{ name }}'
    dest: '{{foo_destination_path}}'
    owner: foo
    group: foo
    mode: '0644'

  when: "'bar' == {{ type }}"

- name: move bar

  copy:
    src: '{{ bar_root_path }}/{{ name }}'
    dest: '{{bar_destination_path}}'
    owner: bar
    group: bar
    mode: '0644'

  when: "'baz' == {{ type }}"

- name: move baz 

  copy:
    src: '{{ baz_root_path }}/{{ name }}'
    dest: '{{baz_destination_path}}'
    owner: baz
    group: baz
    mode: '0000'
```

What I want to achieve is to use conditionals to find out what the vars prompt is and then access the vars section to do the copy command once substituting the params from vars file instead of three commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html) lookup in order to achieve such a task.
Note that all variables, accessible to that host are accessible via that lookup, might there be from play variables, task variable, inventory variable or imported via `var_files`, the syntax stays the same.

This ables you to look for a variable based on a variable, for example:

```yaml
lookup('vars', type)
```

Would give you the dictionary

```yaml
foo_root_path: faaa
foo_dest_path: baa
```

When `type` is `foo`.

And since your type is also part of your dictionary keys, you will also need to use the tilde symbol `~`, which is the [concatenation operator](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators) in Jinja:

```yaml
"{{ type ~ '_root_path' }}"
```

Would give you the string

```
foo_root_path
```

When `type` is `foo`.

So given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  vars: 
    foo:
      foo_root_path: faaa
      foo_dest_path: baa
    bar:
      bar_root_path: xyz
      bar_dest_path: wxy
    baz:
      baz_root_path: abc
      baz_dest_path: def

  vars_prompt:
    - name: type
      prompt: "What variable type do you want to use?"
      private: no  

  pre_tasks:
    - assert:
        that: lookup('vars', type, default='') | length
      
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 
          root_path: "{{ lookup('vars', type)[type ~ '_root_path'] }}"
          dest_path: "{{ lookup('vars', type)[type ~ '_dest_path'] }}"
```

Here are some runs of it:

- ```
  What variable type do you want to use?: foo

  PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

  TASK [assert] ****************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "changed": false,
      "msg": "All assertions passed"
  }

  TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": {
          "dest_path": "baa",
          "root_path": "faaa"
      }
  }

  PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```
- ```
  What variable type do you want to use?: bar

  PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

  TASK [assert] ****************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "changed": false,
      "msg": "All assertions passed"
  }

  TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": {
          "dest_path": "wxy",
          "root_path": "xyz"
      }
  }

  PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```
- This is making the playbook gracefully fail, in case the prompted variable is not defined, thanks to the [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/assert_module.html) module defined as `pre_tasks`.
  You need to use a `default=''` if the variable is undefined, otherwise, the `vars` lookup will error, [as prompted in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html#parameter-default).
  Then, when you have an empty string from the default, testing its [`length`, via the Jinja filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#length), would evaluate to `false`, if the string happens to be empty, making `length` return `0`, otherwise, if it is a dictionary, the `length` would be a value `> 0` and so, evaluate to `true`.

  ```
  What variable type do you want to use?: evil

  PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

  TASK [assert] ****************************************************************************************************
  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
      "assertion": "lookup('vars', type, default='') | length",
      "changed": false,
      "evaluated_to": false,
      "msg": "Assertion failed"
  }

  PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
  localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
  ```

---

So adapting all this to your case gives this playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  vars: 
    name: file.ext
    foo:
      foo_root_path: faaa
      foo_dest_path: baa
    bar:
      bar_root_path: xyz
      bar_dest_path: wxy
    baz:
      baz_root_path: abc
      baz_dest_path: def

  vars_prompt:
    - name: type
      prompt: "What variable type do you want to use?"
      private: no  

  pre_tasks:
    - assert:
        that: lookup('vars', type, default='') | length
      
  tasks:
    - name: "Move {{ type }} data from source to destination"
      copy:
        src: "{{ lookup('vars', type)[type ~ '_root_path'] }}/{{ name }}"
        dest: "{{ lookup('vars', type)[type ~ '_dest_path'] }}"
        owner: "{{ type }}"
        group: "{{ type }}"
        mode: "0644"
```

Comment: few follow up questions please : in pretasks does the default empty mean empty ? what does length do? also could you please explain.  [type ~ '_root_path'] does the tilde join the type with root path ?

Comment: one more question please would be:my vars file is in a separate yaml file and not defined as vars section in playbook itself .My vars are just accessed in my playbook as vars_files section. So then would thelookup statement be :   lookup('var_files', type, default='')|length

Comment: All those question are now answered in the [edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63403539/revisions)

Comment: "msg": "The conditional check 'lookup('vars_files', data_type, default='')|length' failed. The error was: lookup plugin (vars_files) not found"

Comment: As aid in the second sentence of the answer, the syntax is the same, might the variable come from play variables, task variable, inventory variable or imported via `var_files`. So you have to use: `lookup('vars', data_type, default='') | length`